# How to normalizate a schema in 2NF and 3NF?

Tags: schema, normalization, database-normalization

If I have the schema R=(A,B,C,D,E) and the set of functional dependences F={AE->B, AB->C, AC->D}. The key is AE.
I should transform it in 2NF and 3NF.

I did this:
R1=(A,C,D)
R2=(A,E,B)

But I am not sure it's ok because I lost the depedance AB->C

Comment: If you lost a FD going to 3NF then you should be *sure* it's not ok. Show how you got that.

Comment: While you're thinking about this (cough), you should know that there's no guarantee that you can normalize a relation to 2NF *and no further*, or that you can normalize a relation to 3NF *and no further*. This is a common misunderstanding.